# Cannot Upgrade Google Cloud SQL to Second Generation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, console-server

I cannot upgrade the First generation Google Cloud Instance to Second generation instance using MySQL Second Generation upgrade wizard in console.
During the check configuration screen, I get **Tables that use the MEMORY storage engine found** error due to which I cannot proceed further as shown in screenshot =>
[Error Message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJIcs.jpg)

According to documentation at [Upgrading a First Generation instance to Second Generation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen), I have verified using the query below

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE engine = 'MEMORY' AND
   table_schema NOT IN
   ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

but found no tables using a MEMORY storage engine.

[Screenshot of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M011m.jpg)

[Screenshot of query execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrELO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a quick scan or sort of the “Type” column, In this example below.

With this query you will see the tables type, 
Replace ‘database’ with your database name, adapt the query to your data.

SELECT TABLE_NAME,

ENGINE

FROM information_schema.TABLES

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' and ENGINE = 'myISAM'

Comment: This doesn't work. I have no myISAM tables in my database. Still cloud console continues to throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the error and proceeded with upgrade. I had a to remove a table from the performance_schema database that did not use the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA storage engine before starting the upgrade process. Seems Google Cloud console threw in an **irrelevant error**!